# Should I be using "Organization Accounts" when beginning the adoption of Azure?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We are spinning up a development against Microsoft Azure and will be making use of Visual Studio Online in conjunction with Microsoft Azure capabilities (PaaS, and IaaS). The majority of our developers will have MSDN subscriptions.

To get started I have set up the Azure Portal with what is being called a "Microsoft Account" (definition based on the FAQ below). I did this in order to establish a POC and demonstration but now I am wondering if this account needs to be an "Organizational Account."  My company does use Office365/Outlook so I think it is possible to establish "Organizational Accounts" but I have not been able to determine with our Operations resources what would be necessary.

The question then is should I be using strictly Organizational Accounts for all Azure and Visual Studio Online accounts?  If an account has already been set up as a Microsoft account can it be transitioned to an Organizational account? Are there any implications to be aware of?

One of the problems I am currently experiencing is that I cannot be logged into Outlook and Azure at the same time (assume Chrome for this example) unless I use Incognito mode for one of the sites.  I am using the same email account for both but for Outlook it is being treated as an organizational account but for Azure it is a Microsoft account.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531048.aspx

Comment: I found this FAQ that may answer many of your questions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531048.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Org Accounts only once you have your domain synced to WAAD. This is what we have concluded is the best way to move forward and now are waiting on the Infrastructure gods to approve syncing our AD with WAAD. ...be prepared for resistance in this area.

The link to the FAQ says to contact MS to transition MS to Org account.

We have found this to be a very messy area with little direction from Microsoft to be found. We are not yet adopting VSO until we can use Org\WAAD accounts. They say new VSO accounts now support Org\WAAD accounts but if you have already created a VSO account you currently cannot switch over to Org\WAAD.